# Why can we neglect the inertial (but not viscous) term in Navier-Stokes at low flow and high viscosity?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering

**Why can we neglect the inertial (but not viscous) term in Navier-Stokes at low flow and high viscosity?**

Complete Navier-Stokes: $\rho \frac{D\vec{v}}{Dt}=\rho g - \nabla P+ \mu \nabla ^2 \vec{v}$

Inertial term:
$\frac{D\vec{v}}{Dt}=
\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}+
\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial x}v_x+
\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial y}v_y+
\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial z}v_z$.

And as we assume a stationary flow and low rate: $
\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}=0, 
\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial x}\approx0,
\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial y}\approx0,
\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial z}\approx0$. And so it follows that the inertial term can be ignored.

However in my material it is also stated that the $\mu \nabla ^2 \vec{v}$ will be the dominating term during these circumstances. Why will it not be so that $\nabla ^2 \vec{v} \rightarrow
\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial x^2}\approx0,
\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial y^2}\approx0,
\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial z^2}\approx0
\rightarrow \mu \nabla ^2 \vec{v} \approx 0$ as well?

Comment: Can you cite the book/document/etc. that made this claim?  It would help to see it in context.

Comment: The course book is "Fundamentals of Momentum, Heat and Mass Transfer" by Welty, Rorrer and Foster.
Unfortunately this is a problem in a practice problem document in Swedish, so I am not sure if it will be of much help.

Comment: I have the 4th edition of that book (English version).  I will look and see if they explain more.

Comment: It is quite a significant mistake/misprint to state $\partial_\beta u_\alpha \approx 0$ and i can understand your confusion concerning the second derivatives! If the practice problem is made by a TA/professor (s)he should really review the basics of fluid mechanics...

Comment: @nluigi I don't see where you're getting the $\partial_\beta u_\alpha \approx 0$ from the OP's question, or even what that expression means. What are $\beta$ and $\alpha$, and what is the differential wrt?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin - it's index notation; substitute $\alpha=[x,y,z]$ and $\beta=[x,y,z]$ to get the $x,y,z$ components of the derivative and velocity. My point is the claim $\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial x}\approx0,
\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial y}\approx0,
\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial z}\approx0$ is incorrect for 'low-rate'. see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Usually what is implied by low flowrate and high viscosity is that we are dealing with a so-called low Reynolds number flow. The Reynolds number is dimensionless number which is the ratio of inertial forces ($\rho U U$) and viscous force ($\mu U/L$):
$$\mathrm{Re}=\frac{\rho U U}{\mu U/L}=\frac{\rho U L}{\mu}$$
For low $\mathrm{Re}$ viscous forces dominate (laminar regime) and for high $\mathrm{Re}$ inertial forces dominate (turbulent regime). Dimensionless numbers like $\mathrm{Re}$ show up naturally through a process known as 'scaling' in which the equations are made non-dimensional; through this process it is then possible to say which terms are negligible based on the values of relevant dimensionless numbers. For more information check my answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197848/why-is-the-reynolds-number-the-way-it-is-why-is-its-order-the-way-it-is/197852#197852) question.

Technically, saying 'low flow and high viscosity' is not sufficient to say we are dealing with a low $\mathrm{Re}$ flow because it also depends on the length scale $L$ (usually a pipe diameter, etc) and the density $\rho$ (of air or water), but it is usually implied that is the case.

Now saying for a low flowrate that $\partial_\beta u_\alpha \approx 0$ is incorrect; what you probably mean is that $u_\beta\partial_\beta u_\alpha \ll \mu\partial_\beta^2u_\alpha$. This justifies the simplification of the equations by saying that $u_\beta\partial_\beta u_\alpha\approx 0$ which physically means that inertial terms are completely negligible compared to viscous terms. $u_\beta\partial_\beta u_\alpha\approx 0$ does not imply $\partial_\beta u_\alpha \approx 0$ rather the low flowrate implies $u_\beta\approx0$ while $\partial_\beta u_\alpha$ can be significant. Consider the order-of-magnitude estimation of $\partial_\beta u_\alpha \sim U/L$; for small values of $L$ (contributes to low $\mathrm{Re}$) it may be much larger than order $O(U)$. A similar order-of-magnitude analysis of the viscous terms $\partial_\beta^2 u_\alpha \sim U/L^2$ shows that these will be even more significant. Hence, the reason why the inertial terms are negligible but the viscous terms are not.

Answer (score 2):

Since the final term is proportional to $\nabla ^2 \vec{v}$, and not $|\vec{v}|$, the term can be large even if the velocity magnitude is small. Consider the simple case of no-slip laminar flow in an x-oriented pipe. This is a unidirectional flow, so we can discard $v$ and $w$ and focus on $u$. We'll take as given that the flow speed is small.

Just because $u$ is generally small, however, doesn't mean we can conclude that $\nabla u$ is also generally small. In fact, the narrower the pipe, the larger the magnitude of $\nabla u$. Looking at the gradient field of the horizontal velocity, we see it tends to point inwards, towards the center of the pipe, where the velocity is at a maximum. This means we have an negative divergence, for which the magnitude is dependent on the *sharpness of the variation* in the velocity, and not its overall magnitude.

Hence $\nabla ^2 \vec{v} = \{-|\nabla ^2 u|, 0, 0\}$ is not insignificant, which of course is just Navier Stokes accurately predicting the tendency of viscous forces to cause a pressure drop in steady state, horizontal pipe flow (or you could call it the necessity of a pressure drop to force flow against viscous forces, as you please). Cancel out the gravitational and time varying terms and see for yourself.